# How do i update a column with specific values to reference the primary key ID of another table?

Tags: sql-server, join, key

My goal is to normalize my table. My table before normalization is called Product Specifications, to normalize it I have two other tables called `buyers_table` and `product_table`

Table "Product Specifications"

Columns: Product_id , model_number, buyer

Buyers_table

Column: Buyer_id, buyer

Product_table

product_id, model_number, buyer_id

How do I insert the buyers from my `product_specification` table into my `product_table` but have the values show up as the `buyer_id` value instead of buyer?

Sorry I am new to this. This is a simplified version of the database that I have set up for my company.

Comment: This is in SQL Server by the way

Answer (score 0):

**use this design for database**

> Product_buyer:   Columns:Id, Product_id , Buyer_id
>
> Buyers_table:   Column: Id, Buyername
>
> Product_table:    Id, Model_number
>
> Product_Specifications: Id,Product_id,Productname,Price

**then For insert data to database**

1. First enter the information in the Product_table table
2. Retrieve the latest Product_table table record and enter Id as Product_id and the other of the information in the Product_Specifications table.
3. Enter the buyer information in the Buyers_table table when purchasing
4. Product_buyer

**Create tables**

```
create table Product_table
  (
    Id int identity,
    Model_number int,
    primary key(Id));


    create table Product_Specifications
    (Id int identity,
     Product_id int,
     Productname nvarchar(150),
     Price int,
     primary key(ID),
     foreign key(Product_id) references Product_table);

   //**********************
     //and define other table
   //......................
```

**Retrieve product information**

```
select Product_table.Id,Product_table.Model_number,Product_Specifications.Productname,Productname.Price
from Product_table join Product_Specifications
on Product_table.Id = Product_Specifications.Product_id
```

**Retrieve Product_buyer information**

```
select Product_table.Id,Product_table.Model_number,Product_Specifications.Productname,Productname.Price,Buyers_table.Id,Buyers_table.Buyername
from Buyers_table join Product_buyer on Buyers_table.Id = Product_buyer.Buyer_id
join Product_table on Product_buyer.Product_id = Product_table.Id
join Product_Specifications on Product_table.Id = Product_Specifications.Product_id
```